# CookieUtils returns null on load

Tags: java, cookies

I am writing a Wicket web application and using the CookieUtils class to save and retrieve cookie values. Here is my code (inside StartPage.java):

```
CookieDefaults cookieDefaults = new CookieDefaults();
cookieDefaults.setMaxAge( COOKIE_MAX_AGE );

CookieUtils cookies = new CookieUtils( cookieDefaults );

cookies.save( "guid", guid );
cookies.save( "lang", "en" );
cookies.save( "verified", "" );

String loadedGuid = new CookieUtils().load( "guid" );
```

When I output loadedGuid to the console or debug it using Eclipse, it returns null, even though I have verified that 'guid' is being written correctly through Chrome debug.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Weird. All day yesterday I could not get hold of a cookie value using the .load method. Came back today and it worked, without any changes to the code.